# Force Windows 11 to not use PIN for login? (Password login option is missing)

Tags: passwords, windows-11, lock-screen, pin

I have a Windows 11 pc that has a PIN on it that I do not remember setting, but this normally would not be a problem as I know the password for the computer. **However, the password option is missing from the login screen.** I have seen computers running Windows 10 and 11 in the past sometime at the login screen say "Something is wrong with the PIN, please use the password to login."

Is there any way to force this to happen and revert it even temporarily to allow the password to be used for login?

Comment: In Sign In options, uncheck Require Windows Hello for log on.

Comment: @John How am I supposed to get to sign in options if I’m locked out?

Comment: Try resetting the PIN from another computer.